# Python Returns none instead of True or False

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a function called isSiete() that will accept an integer from a txt file with 5000 random numbers.

Return True if the second column digit (The ‘tens’ column) of the number is a ‘7’ and False if it is not.

```
def isSiete(num):
    numString = str(num)
    numList = list(numString)
    numSum = 0
    for i in numList:
        if ('0' + i)[-2] == '7':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I expect the output to be True but I am getting False everytime.
I've tried the following test numbers

isSiete(7777)
isSiete(4774)
isSiete(672)

Comment: `numList = list(numString)` - string is already a list

Comment: Why do you have a loop?

Comment: @Evgeny. String is already a sequence, not a list. A sequence is something you can index that has a length. A list is an instance of the list class.

Comment: `'0'+i` isn't doing that you think; try using a debugger.

Comment: `numString = str(num)`, `numList = list(numString)`, `for i in numList` means that `i` is always one character, `'0' + i` is always two characters, and `('0' + i)[-2]` is always `'0'`.

Comment: This is only ever checking once ..... then it returns from the function. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: In the post title you say it returns none, but in the question you say it returns false.  Which is it?

Comment: @Evgeny a `str` object is not a `list`, however, I think what you meant to say is that `str` objects are iterable like `list` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with strings at all; it's an order of magnitude faster to divide by 10 twice.

```
def isSiete(num):
    return num // 10 % 10 == 7
```

The arithmetic gets slower as the size of `num` increases, but this is still faster when `num` is a 17-digit number.

Comment: This is it!! I guess my syntax were messed up. This also worked,    

try:
        return str(num)[-2] == '7'
    except IndexError:
        pass

Answer (score 1):

Your `('0' + i)[-2]` is always equal to the character `'0'`

For example, suppose `numList == ['A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E']`
Suppose that `i` is an element of  `numList`, such as 'P'

Then `'0' + i == "0P"`

`[-2]` gets the second-to-last character
`"0P"[-2] == "0"`

Note that it does not matter what `P` is. The second-to-last character
of `'0' + i` is always `'0'`

`('0' + i)[-2] == '7'` will always return `False`

---

I encourage you to learn about the "modulus operator" (`%`)

`x % 10` is the remainder of x divided by 10.
For example, `74 % 10 == 4`

In general `x % y` is the remainder of `x` when divided by `y`

To extract a specific digit out of a number, do the following:

```
def extract_digit(number, position):
    """
    position == 1 ......if you want the ones place
    position == 2 ......if you want the tens place
    position == 3 ......if you want the hundredths place
    position == 4 ......if you want the thousanths place
    and so on...
    """ 
    small_places = number % (10**position)
    digit = small_places //(10**(position - 1))
    return digit
```

For example, suppose you want the hundred's place of `123456789`:

```
123456789 % 1000 == 789      
789 // 100 == 7
```

As a final result, we have:

```
def isSiete(num):
    return extract_digit(num, 2) == 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the converted string to check for your condition as a string in python works as an array of characters:

```
def isSiete(num):
    numString = str(num)
    tensPosition = len(numString) - 2

    if tensPosition >= 0 and numString[tensPosition] == '7':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you asked for help to debug your code or if you wanted some help with a working solution.

In the case you wanted a solution: here's a working snippet which may help you achieve what you wanted.

```py
def is_siete(num):
    """
    Asserts that the tens of a number is 7. Returns False if not.
    """
    num_as_str = str(num)

    try:

        second_num_as_str = num_as_str[-2]
        second_num_as_int = int(second_num_as_str)

        if second_num_as_int == 7:
            return True

        return False

    except IndexError:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(is_siete(7777))  # True
    print(is_siete(4774))  # True
    print(is_siete(672))  # True
    print(is_siete(17))  # False
    print(is_siete(7))  # False
```

Comment: This can be done in one line `return len(str(num)) > 1 and str(num)[-2] == '7'`.

Comment: Indeed. Nice one.

Comment: Hi I was looking for a solution and I've found it from all the helpful people here! thank you also for the working solution!